# limit of an exponentiated sum

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, summation, exponential-function

equation 2 of [this paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2506-learning-with-local-and-global-consistency.pdf) states that

$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{t-1}(\alpha S)^i = (I - \alpha S)^{-1}
$$

In this case $0 < \alpha < 1$ and the entries of $S$ are in the range $[-1, 1]$. How can I understand why this is true?

Comment: It is a result analogous to the sum of a geometric sequence of real numbers.

Comment: The statement will hold whenever the sum converges.  Notably, the information that you gave us is not enough to deduce that this sum will converge.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:  "the entries of $S$ are in the range $[−1,1]$."

But in the paper we have the eigenvalues of $S$ are in  $[−1,1]$.

In this case each eigenvalue of $ \alpha S$ are in the intervall $(-1,1)$, since $0< \alpha <1.$

Hence the spectral radius of $ \alpha S$  is $<1,$ therefore the geometric series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(\alpha S)^i$ is convergent and $ = (I - \alpha S)^{-1}.$

Comment: Fred , that you write is true but is not easy to prove. The standard method is to say that when $\rho(A)<1$, there is an operator norm $N$ s.t. $N(A)<1$.